# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component using react-apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo

I get this error trying to use react-apollo from a public [graphql api](https://countries.trevorblades.com/).

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
>   function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I've read [react documentations](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) and I'm sure the problem is not one of those three reasons.

It's a simple project using `create-react-app`. Both `react` and `react-dom` versions are `16.10.2`.

#### app.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

const query = gql`
  {
    countries {
      name
      code
    }
  }
`;

function App() {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState('US');
    const onCountryChange = event => {
      setCountry(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Query query={query}>
          {result => {
            if (result.loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
            if (result.error) return <p>{result.error.message}</p>;
            return (
              <select value={country} onChange={onCountryChange}>
                {result.data.countries.map(country => (
                  <option key={country.code} value={country.code}>
                    {country.name}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            );
          }}
        </Query>
      </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

#### index.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./app";
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://countries.trevorblades.com'
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I'm new to graphql and apollo and have no idea what could be the reason for this error.

### Update

As @Joseph suggested, I've extracted a component out of app and used `useQuery`, and now the code looks like this:

#### Select.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Select(props) {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('US');
  const onCountryChange = event => {
    setCountry(event.target.value); // already called within the function component
  };

  return (
    <select value={country} onChange={onCountryChange}>
      {props.countries.map(country => (
        <option key={country.code} value={country.code}>
          {country.name}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
export default Select;
```

#### app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import Select from './select';

const query = gql`
  {
    countries {
      name
      code
    }
  }
`;

function App() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(query);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
       {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
       {error &&  <p>{error.message}</p>}
       <Select countries={data.countries} />
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

No changing in `index.js`, But I still get the same error.

### Update 2:

I was missing installing `@apollo/react-hooks` but twhen I installed it, I got a new error now:

> Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap
>   the root component in an , or pass an ApolloClient
>   instance in via options.

### Update 3:

This is getting long but I've imported `ApolloProvider`from `@apollo/react-hooks` in `index.js` to fix the last issue:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
```

And now i get

> TypeError: data is undefined

In this line from `app.js`:

```
  <>
   {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
   {error &&  <p>{error.message}</p>}
   <Select countries={data.countries} />  // <= This line causes error
  </>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong withe first code you provided. If you have an error, it's elsewhere. Here's the exact same code running fine in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-snowflake-kdyik

Comment: @MarouaneFazouane But it's all the project so far, Could be codesandbox be different with `create-react-app` in something?

Comment: I don't think so. Try stopping then re-running `yarn start` or something?

Comment: @MarouaneFazouane This left me with second error in update 2

Comment: @AlexJolig `{ data && data.countries && <Select countries={data.countries} /> }`

Comment: @JosephD. wOw!! Finally! What does this line means? Also why did you remove the answer? It works now!

Comment: @AlexJolig it's ok. I don't feel showing long answers. lol Anyway, the line basically is a [conditional render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html). Would need to ensure that `data` **and** `data.countries` are both defined (not null) to be able to render the `Select` component. Happy to know everything is fine now.

Comment: @JosephD. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error while I was using react-apollo with the `graphql` API made with `nestjs`, I have tried first `componentWillMount()`

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)You might be breaking the Rules of HooksYou might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

So I have fixed like is shown in the code below:

### Home.js

```
import { useLazyQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {  GET_ALL_PROJECTS } from '../graphql/Queries'
function Home() {
    const [getEmployees, { loading, data, error }] = useLazyQuery(GET_ALL_PROJECTS,
        {
            variables: {}
        });

    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    if (data) {
        console.table(data)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
               getEmployees();
            }, []);
return (
        <div className="home">...</div>
}

export default Home
```